# More interesting name for our main chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

Most sites use interesting and humorous chat room names related to their site topic, like

- /dev/chat (Unix  &Linux)
- The DMZ (Security)
- Root Access (Super User)
- The 2nd Monitor (Code Review)
- The Nineteenth Byte (Programming Puzzles & Code Golf)
- The Bridge (Arqade)
- The Heap - Consultancy (Database Admins)
- The h Bar (Physics)
- The Periodic Table (Chemistry)
- The Maid Cafe (Anime & Manga)
- The Hangar (Aviation)
- The Frying Pan (Cooking)
- etc.

Why do we have such a generic name like **Ask Ubuntu General Room**?

And could we eventually collect name proposals, vote on them and then finally change it?

Comment: I don't want to have to redo the advert for chat I made! :P

Comment: "The Year of the Linux Desktop Room" - that should last us for a few years :D _(I'll see myself out...)_

Comment: "The 2nd Monitor" would be funny since ubuntu doesn't seem to save monitor settings on reboot, i hope the new LTS fixes this.

Comment: FYI Arquade is spelt Arqade (no u, so that it says arQAde)

Comment: UbuNuts? That would be fun

Answer (score 21):

How about
*Talk Ubuntu?*

It shows that it is a channel for discussion rather than Q&A.

Comment: I like this too, I was just suggesting this. Ask Ubuntu and Talk Ubuntu go well together.

Comment: Previously, on AMC's Talking Dead....

Comment: Talk Ubuntu sounds a lot like askubuntu chat.

Comment: @HenryWHHack Thats the point, it fits well with Ask Ubuntu and is clear what it is :)

Comment: I don't like this. It's hardly different from what we already have ("Ask Ubuntu General Room") and it just doesn't feel like much of a name.

Answer (score 18):

A suggestion with a variation:

- **apt-chat ubuntu**
- **sudo apt-chat ubuntu**

Comment: I like the chatty chupacabras, sound like an special Ubuntu Release :)

Comment: It would be easier to vote on a new name if you made one answer per proposal. So I'd put the chatty chupa-thing into a seperate post, the other two are similar enough IMO.

Comment: @ByteCommander I tried making an answer with the last 2 lines of this one, but it kept being submitted as a comment... Possibly for being too short? It was really strange. Also, I just saw this now, and 6 people already voted...

Comment: Actually 10 people voted, you currently have (+8 | -2)

Comment: Okay, I will submit another answer then, with the CC one

Comment: @ByteCommander alright, done.

Comment: @Videonauth you may one to vote [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15312/474925) since I separated the suggestions.

Comment: What about `apt-get chat`?

Answer (score 17):

/dev/random

It reflects the content of the chat.

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: *Pffffft* Great, now I need to clean up my screen.

Comment: /dev/random or /dev/urandom?

Answer (score 17):

I'd like something along the lines of Oxwivi's answer, however just to throw in another one (perhaps a bit banal, fantasy is not my top strenght):

## The Orange Room

It's Ubuntu's color and the room's color.

Comment: This isn't so bad.

Comment: @Seth Totally agreed

Comment: I'm backing this one 100%. Not to say the other suggestions weren't good enough but this keeps the "room" moniker in the title and still uniquely identifies us.

Comment: Is Ubuntu not purple?

Comment: What about **The Orange Bar** (mixing this answer with http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16083/367990)?

Answer (score 15):

Ubuntu comes in [multiple flavours](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours):

- Ubuntu
- Lubuntu
- Kubuntu
- …

So I suggest **Chatbuntu**.

Comment: ahem! This sounds a very nasty word in our language (Bengali).

Comment: Chat**u**buntu.

Answer (score 12):

I think we've got a great opportunity in that the letter C was skipped in naming Ubuntu versions.  I propose "Chatty Capybara"

Answer (score 11):

Chatroom for Humans, maybe? Or at least something to that tone.

Comment: Yes, adapting the meaning of "Ubuntu" sounds like a nice idea to me. (*Ubuntu is an ancient African word meaning ‘humanity to others’. It also means ‘I am what I am because of who we all are’. The Ubuntu operating system brings the spirit of Ubuntu to the world of computers.* - from http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu)

Comment: Of all the answers, so far, I like this idea most. "Chatroom for Humans" may not be the one but it is a good concept.

Comment: Ubuntu's motto is "Linux for Human beings", so maybe "chat for human beings"? It's kinda cool, but very hard to figure out what the topic is.. Probably should leave it either what it is or something else (mostly) obvious..

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this would be appreciated, but what if we renamed our chatroom every 6 months when a new release comes out and use the codename's animal and its living place as inspiration.

Example:

- 14.04: The Tahr Mountain
- 14.10: The Unicorn Sky
- 15.04: The Vervet Savanna
- 15.10: The Werewolf Moon
- 16.04: The Xerus Tree
- ...

I see that renaming the main room of a site that frequently is probably not too practical (posts mentioning the old name become obsolete, the must be a new meta poll for the next name every half a year, somebody of the moderators has to actually rename it, etc.).

However, I'm still proposing this without expecting too much, just to get your opinion and maybe inspire some of you to come up with a better, persistent name.

Comment: Alternatively we could also only switch the names for LTS releases, that would mean every two years. Probably a better compromise.

Comment: You didn't followed the official pattern, the 2 words should begin with the same letter. :(

Comment: Whenever we get around to 'Y': Ubuntu 0 LTS: Yakety Yard

Comment: 'X' is a hard one to find a synonym for talk, chat, yak, etc.  And unfortunately the next LTS release skips Y altogether. :-(  But I love the idea!  And "Yakety Yard" in particular.

Answer (score 8):

### Taco Tuesday

As per our fond love of tacos http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Taco&room=201 , and of course the Ubuntu taco truck:

[image]

Comment: Why does Ubuntu have a taco truck? Or is that a taco truck running Ubuntu? Or an Ubuntu truck filled with tacos?

Comment: Tacos are awesome, [but bacon is **more awesome**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=bacon&user=&room=201).

Answer (score 6):

I like [Onebree's idea](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15295/85695), but I think that a single word is better and easier to type. So how about simply

### apt-chat

Answer (score 5):

Here's a second option. This time, piggy-backing off of [Ryan](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15280/474925):

- **Chatty Chupacabras**

Answer (score 4):

How about *The progress bar*? That punning both with the double meaning of *bar* (a place to buy alcohol or, often in computing, a progress bar) and *progress* since Ubuntu is the OS of the future etc, etc.

Sort of like this but without the ugly Windows overtones:

[image: progress bar]

Comment: What about **The Orange Bar** (mixing this answer with http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15301/367990)?

Comment: Something going on? What's with the resurgence of this question? 

Answer (score 3):

Quite frankly, I rather like that we have a staid name. It says: we have things to chat about, instead of spending time thinking of names for our chatroom.

Comment: You [weren't](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3795/136107) this grumpy about the U&L chatroom name :P

Comment: @cat at the time, one of my worries was that AU would do something like this. We didn't, and I was relieved.

Comment: I agree. I don't see the need for a name change. My reasoning is [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16761/225694)

Answer (score 3):

Following the trend of the various misspellings of Ubuntu, how about:

## Ubanter

And, just in case the pun's not obvious:

> ban·ter  (băn′tər)
>
> n.
>
> Good-humored, playful, or teasing conversation.

Answer (score 2):

I realize I'm late to the party here, but I've affectionately referred to The Ask Ubuntu General Chat Room as "The Water Cooler" as it's where I typically go to find someone who isn't too busy working to help! ;-) Be that as it may, I don't actually see the need for a new name for the room as the current name makes it easy to find. After reviewing something on the order of 5000 posts here, I would hesitate to add another [level of confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291185/260418) for members (new and old) to overcome.

Comment: Unfortunately that name is already taken by the general room of Workplace SE https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler

Comment: @ByteCommander Ah well, A rose by any other name. As long as we can find it, I doubt it matters what we call it.

Answer (score 0):

In honor of Mark Shuttleworth, the creator of Ubuntu, I suggest to change the name to **The Chattleworth**.

Answer (score 0):

## Talkbuntu

**Chatbuntu** was suggested. But no one suggested **Talkbuntu**

It reflects on multi-flavor of Ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: I have a better idea**

I suggest: `apt-get moo`

Old answer: I vote `sudo apt-get chat` or something similar.

Answer (score -3):

### The Sandwich Shop

or anything else related to making sandwiches.

[image: Mandatory XKCD comic (sudo make me a sandwich)]

Answer (score -5):

***The Well***, I suggest.

Comment: Would you explain your idea a bit, please? I don't understand it...

Comment: That's where people met when they get their water.

Comment: Yes... I know what a well is, but I don't understand what this has to do with Ubuntu or this site?

Comment: Okay, that was not clear to me the way you asked. For the picture: it's pretty much a real life example of a chatroom (despite not indoor but normally outdoor, but I think there are indoor wells as well). It also symbolizes community

Answer (score -5):

### Canonical

How about it? It can represent:

- The Philosophical [Idea](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canonical)
- The [company](https://www.canonical.com/) behind Ubuntu

Answer (score -8):

I suggest *Talk with Human beings* or *Meet Humans*

Answer (score -10):

UbuntUnity

UbuntUsers Unite

sounds stupid XD

Answer (score -13):

How about Ubuntu Chats? I'ts a great idea.. (il sort myself out)

Comment: WHO VOTED -3 FOR MY IDEA???

Comment: I did, all four of them. Kidding, didn't vote on it :)